# VGG19 weights became NaN in all layers after single literation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nan

I am practicing neural style transfer with pre-trained model of VGG19. When I execute the training, after 1 iteration, all the weights in all layers of VGG19 become NaN. And when I skip the part where I do sess.run() on the cost functions, the weights remain the same, as expected. But does it mean that my cost functions are causing the issue?

```py
def model_nst(sess, input_image, num_iterations = 2):

    # Initialize global variables (you need to run the session on the initializer)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Run the noisy input image (initial generated image) through the model.
    sess.run(model['input'].assign(input_image))

    for i in range(num_iterations):

        # Run the session on the train_step to minimize the total cost
        sess.run(train_step)

        # Compute the generated image by running the session on the current model['input']
        generated_image = sess.run(model['input'])
        print("generated_image:")
        print(generated_image) #becomes NaN too after 1 iteration

        if i%1 == 0:

            #Jc = sess.run(J_content)
            #Js = sess.run(J_style)
            #Jt = sess.run(J)
            #print("Iteration " + str(i) + " :")
            #print("total cost = " + str(Jt))
            #print("content cost = " + str(Jc))
            #print("style cost = " + str(Js))

            # save current generated image in the "/output" directory
            util.save_image(util.CONFIG.OUTPUT_DIR + str(i) + ".png", generated_image)

    # save last generated image
    util.save_image('out/generated_image.jpg', generated_image)

    return generated_image
```

Answer (score 0):

What data are you using to perform transfer learning? The data might have NANs. This might also happen if your data is the wrong shape or type etc.

If the above is checks out, then increase the learning rate or decrease the batch size. The initial weights result in vanishing or exploding gradients. Changing the batch size will bypass this problem.

Comment: Hi Rigo, thanks for reaching out to me! i have checked the input data, they are free of NaN values. VGG19 requires input data type float32, I converted them to np.float32 first, so it should be fine I guess. Size is as required 300x400 :/

Comment: Did you check if your model is properly compiled in tensorflow? Sometimes the model is written in keras or caffe and becomes incompatible when tf is updated to the latest version.

Comment: Are your global variables defined somewhere?

Comment: may I share my repo with you? :/ https://github.com/enyangxxx/neuralStyleTransferMonet